# Facebook share link rel="img_src" - does it have restrictions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We've got rel="img_src" set up correctly on our site, but we're finding in certain cases Facebook refuses to show the image for the link being shared. This has a very detrimental effect on virality; it is the difference between something sinking or swimming.

Sometimes it uses the image, sometimes it does not. But I cannot see a pattern as to how it chooses whether to display a thumbnail. Is it based on image size, or some other factor we can change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re so big on virality :-), then you should maybe use Open Graph meta tags in your pages.

Anyway, I’d guess with the `link rel="img_src"` the same restrictions should apply, as with the og:image tag:

> og:image - An image URL which should represent your object within the graph. The image must be at least 50px by 50px (though minimum 200px by 200px is preferred) and have a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

Not sure if this is totally up-to-date though, because AFAIK the debug tool complains if the og:image is smaller than 200px in each dimension.

Test your pages with the debug tool, it’s handy for figuring out possible problems: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug